# Как с помощью Guzzle получить куки?

Tags: curl, guzzle

Пытаюсь осилить Guzzle 6. Как мне стало понятно, на их сайте краткая документация. Кому охота полноценно поработать с библиотекой, придется лезть в исходники, чтобы воспользоваться другими методами.
Ни в русском, ни в англ инете ответов нет, только как отправить куки.

Вопросик к коллегам - как получить куки с помощью Guzzle?

Краткая документация [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/quickstart.html#cookies) по кукам.
Дистрибутив на [гитхабе](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем разобрался, просто делал запрос на домены, которые не ставят куки.

Получение кук:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://php.net/',
    'cookies'  => true
]);

$req = $client->request('GET', 'http://php.net/');
var_dump($req->getHeaders()['Set-Cookie']);
//0 => string 'COUNTRY=NA%2C91.223.112.255; expires=Sat, 25-Nov-2017 06:43:23 GMT; Max-Age=604800; path=/; domain=.php.net' (length=107)
//1 => string 'LAST_NEWS=1510987403; expires=Sun, 18-Nov-2018 06:43:23 GMT; Max-Age=31536000; path=/; domain=.php.net' (length=102)
```

Или:

```
$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://php.net/',
]);
$r = $client->request('GET', 'http://php.net/', ['cookies'=> $jar]);

var_dump($r->getHeaders()['Set-Cookie']);
```

Отправка кук

```
use GuzzleHttp\Cookie\CookieJar;

$jar = CookieJar::fromArray([
    'name' => 'value_puk'
], 'httpbin.org');

$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['cookies' => true]);
$r = $client->request('GET', 'http://httpbin.org/cookies', ['cookies' => $jar]);

echo $r->getBody();
```

Полученные куки не в совсем удобном виде, теперь их надо как-то распарсивать для дальнейшего использования.